# Как узнать какой макет используется?

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: список макетов]

как узнать какой макет использует Android Studio запуская приложение на эмуляторе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходишь в настройки эмулятора и смотришь параметры экрана
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не то, нужно узнать, какой макет используется когда запускается приложение

Comment: Гугл -> "Android layout qualifiers"